# What's the difference between a AM3, FM1 or FM2 AMD processor?

Tags: cpu, am3

I am thinking about upgrading my computer, and my PC store offers three different branches of AMD processors: AM3, FM1, FM2.

Which technical differences do those branches have?

Is FM1 obsolete (by FM2)?

I have seen that most of FM2 processors have integrated graphics, but AM3 don't. Does that apply to all of them? Are there more differences like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those codes are **sockets**.

- Overview of sockets [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_socket)
- FM1 socket info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_FM1)
- FM2 socket info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_FM2)
- AM3 socket info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM3)

The socket type is just a way to keep track of the physical dimensions and electrical hookups of the CPU socket. Generally sockets will support one or more **generations** of CPU.

When thinking of *upgrading* your computer to something modern, you'll want the most modern CPU available, even if you don't end up buying a high-end one, because an up-to-date processor is always more future-proof than an older one.

The FM2 socket is the newest of the bunch, although the **FM2+** socket (note the + sign) is the actual newest socket offered by AMD. *Kaveri*-generation AMD APUs run in FM2+ sockets.

Kaveri is a significant improvement both in terms of CPU and GPU performance over the older generations. Kaveri is actively in the process of being released to the general public, but an example model number of a Kaveri APU is "A8-7600".

Comment: I have seen that most of FM2 processors have integrated graphics, but AM3 don't. Does that apply to all of them? Are there more differences like that?

Comment: FM2 processors (and some other ones as well) are [APUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_processing_unit). AM3 is old enough that they were released before AMD started their APU initiative. See [here](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/apu/Pages/apu.aspx) for details. The only non-APU socket that's reasonably modern is **AM3+**, which sockets 32nm Bulldozer cores. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_processors) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_FX_microprocessors) for more info.

Comment: For instance, [this](http://shop.amd.com/us/All/Detail/Processor/FD9590FHHKWOF) is a quite beastly, non-APU (no integrated graphics) full-scale AMD CPU based on the Piledriver architecture and running on the AM3+ socket...

Comment: You might also consider non-AMD processors, since, yeah, they're very power inefficient compared to Intel, for instance, see [here](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Core-i7-3770K-vs-AMD-FX-9590)... quite detailed markup... AMD's highest end processor against Intel's **previous-generation** processor... there's just no comparison. The Intel CPU equals it on all-cores benchmark, with better single-threaded performance, 35% less power consumed, and it even has on-board graphics...

Comment: Yes, I also consider Intel, but first I wanted to know the differences between AMD sockets. And thanks for the link to cpuboss.com, it's a great site.

Answer (score 3):

Well I can't exactly rain down my past nostalgic experience like the 2 users the will enviably downvote or post comments not relating nor helping but I can be a judge of history.

Seeing how FM1 Front Bus Speed reaches a whopping 100 MH/z at highest clock, it won't do well and will certainly become a bottleneck real fast, so starting or running any process will slowly cap up the bandwidth on the FSB.

FM2 Allowing better architecture design for multiple processes, but still matching in contacts as of the FM1 but +1 contact, was basically FM2 just being a simple revision product. Along with FM2+ but now I am not one to bet on products from 2011. Definitely not obsolete for 3 years, I mean also inventing the technology to connect the north bridge was definitely some new push forward in processor development.

Oh an the AM3 Socket, ahh, I feel too nostalgic now, It reminds me of my first PC *dream sound effects*. But out of the way AM3 has about +40 contact points so better control, it is definitely common (to even meet the likes of me) but is more of what I like to call the 2012 era. I mean the FSB goes up 2x to 200 MH/z and allows a HyperTransport connection between the RAM and processor itself.

Honestly I don't know why are you buying these sockets, I would go for the LGA1100 myself but I can't help my love for Intel. But honestly speculating your using this for a Server of some sorts. Definitely go for AM3, case and point: Efficiency beats price tag, seeya.

Comment: When you say *nostalgic*, do you mean that they are very old?

Comment: @Oriol Oh no, It just reminds me the days of my old PC which I know recognize as the AM3 socket, thinking back just a couple of years its been so much. I don't know by how many years it technically becomes nostalgic but still I would recommend a much more modern socket that would be compabitle for upgrades. Seriously, for me right now, it would be cheaper to: Buy a new motherboard, adjustable power supply, and an i5 then to actually upgrade my current processor with the same socket. No joke. I'm already looking in the Gigabyte motherboards there under the radar but they make great motherboards